# BeanUtils.copyProperties() throws org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Could not copy property 'xyz' from source to target;

Tags: java, spring

Just upgraded from Spring 4.x to 5.3 and Hibernate 3.x to 5.6. I have one instance of my code where I get unexpected errors. More specifically, it is Spring's BeanUtils.CopyProperties() method that causes the error.

It wants to invoke a setter for a `PersistentSet` (I think that's a Hibernate datatype) with the value `null` and throws a FatalBeanException.

Any idea how to solve that kind of errors?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to not use `BeanUtils`, as the documentation states it is mainly for internal framework usage and links to other suggestions. To add to that I suggest to use something like MapStruct for this to generate dedicated mappers for code instead of relying on reflection.

Comment: Can you maybe provide the Throwable causing the FatalBeanException?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers so far. It turned out that a missing null check in the setter of the collection caused the error. BeanUtils.copyProperties() worked just like it was supposed to do.