# org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target) throws error Could not copy property 'channel' from source to target

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, lombok

This is the source class:

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@JsonSerialize(as = RequestContext.class)
public class RequestContext implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String statusCode;

    private String statusType;
    
    private String txnId;
    
    private int channelId;

    private String channel;

}
```

These are the target class and its parent classes:

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@JsonSerialize(as = Transaction.class)
public class Transaction extends TransactionBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Actors actors = Actors.SENDER;
    private PartnerMaster senderPartner;
    private PartnerMaster receiverPartner;
    private PartnerMaster userPartner;
    private UserMaster senderUser;
    private UserMaster receiverUser;

    private WalletAction adjustmentType;
    private BigDecimal netAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal rollbackAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    private Charges charges = new Charges();

    private List<SystemWalletMaster> systemWallets = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<SystemCdrBean> systemCdr = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Items> products;

    /** generic params for dynamic values. **/
    private HashMap<String, Object> genericParams = new HashMap<>();

}
```

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransactionBase extends TransactionFlags implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int channelId;
    private String channel;
    private String mvnoId;

    private ServiceMaster service = new ServiceMaster();

    private String featureId;

    private String statusCode;
    private String statusCodeReceiver;
    private String statusType;
    private String txnType;
    private String message;

    private String txnId;
    private String requestId;
    private long duration;

    private TransactionCommon transactionCommon;

}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransactionFlags implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** flags . **/
    private boolean rollback;
    
    
    private boolean adjustment;
    private boolean adjustmentSystem;
    private boolean isWhitelisted;
    private boolean adjustCommission;
    private boolean adjustFee;
    private boolean adjustSystemCommission;
    private boolean adjustSystemFee;
    private boolean isLimitExists;
    private boolean isLimitAllServices;
    private boolean isApprovalEnabled;

}
```

Beans copy:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private Transaction transaction;

    @Autowired
    private RequestContext requestContext;

    @Autowired
    private UserContext userContext;

    @Autowired
    private CopyPropertyUtils copyPropertyUtils;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("{}Inside MFS Builder, building Transaction request", CONVERTER);

        copyPropertyUtils.copy(requestContext, transaction);
        
        ..............
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // No implementation is done in post handle of the intercepter
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {

        ..................
    }

}
```

When we try to copy `RequestContext` to `Transaction` we get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at com.sixdee.mfs.base.beans.Transaction$$SpringCGLIB$$0.setChannel(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
```

Followed by this:

```
[2m2024-03-08T12:37:20.803+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m20264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m${sys:LOGGED_APPLICATION_NAME}[nio-9110-exec-1][0;39m [36mc.s.d.b.e.ResponseErrorHandler          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resource Not Found : object is not an instance of declaring class CLASS jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl LINE -2 
[2m2024-03-08T12:37:20.836+05:30[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m20264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m${sys:LOGGED_APPLICATION_NAME}[nio-9110-exec-1][0;39m [36m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Could not copy property 'channel' from source to target]
[2m2024-03-08T12:37:20.836+05:30[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m20264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m${sys:LOGGED_APPLICATION_NAME}[nio-9110-exec-1][0;39m [36mc.s.m.b.s.e.EventManager                [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Event management is in progress...
[2m2024-03-08T12:37:20.836+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m20264[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m${sys:LOGGED_APPLICATION_NAME}[nio-9110-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.HandlerExecutionChain           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception

org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public java.lang.String com.sixdee.mfs.base.beans.Transaction.toString()] on target [RequestContext(statusCode=DFS100, statusType=F, txnId=168421046664246, channelId=1, channel=PORTAL)]
```

All the properties required in the target (`Transaction`) are extended from its parent `TransactionBase`.

1. If we try to move those properties to `Transaction` there will be no error.
2. When we tried to copy `new RequestContext()` to `new Transaction()` rather than the autowired beans there was no error.
3. The copy worked when we removed the `@Scope` annotation.
4. We decompiled the .class file of `Transaction` and found that there were no inherited methods.
5. We gave all the annotations of `Transaction` to `TransactionBase` the error was still occurring.

We are not able to find what is causing this issue, whether it is the issue with the source (**Point-3**) or the issue with the target (**Point-1**), all we can understand is one of the object isn't available, also the property names and types are the same. According to the comment by @M. Deinum in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74519437/beanutils-copyproperties-throws-org-springframework-beans-fatalbeanexception) I believe the issue is with the `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils` but the answer says something else.

We are using `@Autowired` in some scenarios and `@AllArgsConstructor` in some other scenarios for dependency injection, would that be causing any issues? Also, the `RequestContext` is a bean in parent maven project and the others are in the child maven project which depends on the parent.

**Versions**

Java 17

Spring Boot 3.2.0

Comment: As I mentioned ni that answer (or rather comment) don't use `BeanUtils` for copying as the intend is for internal use. Use a proper mapping framework like MapStruct instead. Also `@Scope` will create a proxy for the class, which can (and thus will) lead to interesting side effects as it uses reflection to invoke things rather then direct method calls.

Comment: The root of your problem is the Cglib proxy caused by the `@Scope` as @M. Deinum says.   I think a solution lies in using some kind of Factory Bean pattern where Spring asks your code to generate a new Bean for the Web Request and then you can be in control of the Transaction/Base instantiation

Answer (score 0):

when you use `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` it'll use CGLIB to create a class-based proxy. So the objects of type `Transaction` and `RequestContext` aren't the real instances, they're proxies to the concrete classes, like Andrew and M.Deinum said in the comment section. You'll need to use the concrete implementation instead of the proxy.